# What is the difference between 'divert' and 're-route'?

Tags: word-choice

Because of an accident, my train was diverted or 're-routed' to another station?

Are they both correct? If so, which one is more common in colloquial AmE?

Comment: I would tend to choose *rerouted* for vehicles and *diverted* for railway trains: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=train+was+diverted%2Ctrain+was+rerouted%2Ctraffic+was+diverted%2Ctraffic+was+rerouted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrain%20was%20diverted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrain%20was%20rerouted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraffic%20was%20diverted%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctraffic%20was%20rerouted%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Please note that within the travel and transportation industry, these terms may have specific meanings that are different from those understood by the general population.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understating is that:

- To **divert** means to force off the predefined path, emphasis on the fact that it is *not the original way*, it's different now.
- To **re-route** means to put on a different path, emphasis on *reaching the destination* by other means or ways (yet still reaching it).

Comment: Agreed. For example, if an airplane cannot land at the intended destination, e.g., due to snow, it is _diverted_ to another city. The passengers might have to take a bus to the intended destination, because the plane could not get them there.